# How to describe the solution set of polynomial equation $ \textbf{F}(\textbf{y}-\textbf{x})=\textbf{0}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to understand how to approach the solution set of $n$-dimensional system of polynomial equations in $2n$ unknowns over $\mathbb{C}$ of type

$F^k(y^1 - x^1,...,y^{n} - x^{n})=0, k=1,...,n$.

I know that in 1-dimensional case with two unknowns, the set {$(x,y)| F(y-x)=0$} is a diagonal line $y=x+a$, where $F(a)=0$.

I am aware that for dimensions two or higher this is a topic of algebraic geometry, I am just looking for directions. My question is what is the set

{$(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})|\textbf{F}(\textbf{x} - \textbf{y})=\textbf{0}$} in 2-dimensional case?

Comment: I think you have to be more precise : what are the unknowns ? the $x^i$'s, the $y^i$'s ? both ? In the latter case, this is not $n$ unknowns but $2n$ so I doubt it is what you mean but then the 1-dimensional case may suggest otherwise. In the end, I don't know how the answer will be very different from this case but again, this may be because I did not fully understand your question.

Comment: I apologize, you are right, there are $2n$ unknowns. Edited.

Comment: Ok, then this is just like in the 1-dimensional case. For each solution of the system, $\mathbf{a}$, you consider the $n$-plane $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{a}$. Hence, the set of solution is just a union of these $n$-planes. This is thus a trivial vector bundle of rank $n$ over $\{\mathbf{a}~|~ F(\mathbf{a})=0\}$.

Comment: shall I say that $n$-plane is a hyperplane of dimension $n-1$ in $n$-dimensional space?

Comment: No a $n$-plane is an affine space of dimension $n$ in any dimensional space. In your situation this is a $n$-plane in a $2n$-dimensional space.